# What is the correct way to calculate number of DNS queries/second using Get-DnsServerStatistics?

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of DNS queries/second for each domain controller using PowerShell [`Get-DnsServerStatistics`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/get-dnsserverstatistics?view=windowsserver2019-ps). I copied some of the relevant outputs below.

I try to figure out what is the time period of getting 11793847 "TotalQueries" ?

Under section "TimeStatistics," does the field "TimeElapsedSinceLastClearStatisticsBetweenRestart" with value 00:00:28 means 28 seconds? There is another field "TimeElapsedSinceServerStart" has value 34.01:35:21 and I don't understand what it means? maybe 34 days 1 hour 35 min 21 second?
But if there are 28 seconds with total 11793847 DNS queries. i.e. 421208 queries/second is seems not true in our environment. Could you please help me out?

```
TimeStatistics:
==============

**TimeElapsedSinceLastClearedStatisticsBetweenRestart     00:00:28**
LastClearTime                                           9/7/2021 9:33:20 PM
ServerStartTime                                         9/7/2021 9:33:20 PM
TimeElapsedSinceLastClearedStatistics                   34.01:35:21
TimeElapsedSinceServerStartBetweenRestart               00:00:28
**TimeElapsedSinceServerStart                             34.01:35:21**

Query2Statistics:
================

TypeAll                                                 1917
TKeyNego                                                0
TypeOther                                               897431
**TotalQueries                                            11793847**
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions about the time formats are correct. The `*BetweenRestart` times are the offline times of your DNS service. The time you are looking for is

```
TimeElapsedSinceLastClearedStatistics - TimeElapsedSinceLastClearedStatisticsBetweenRestart
```

This is the timespan in which your DNS service was actually answering queries (`34.01:34:53`). I recommend to parse the timespans into [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) objects using `[System.TimeSpan]::Parse("34.01:35:21")`, for example. Then you can easily subtract the timespans like shown above.

The resulting timespan object offers you the `TotalSeconds` member attribute, which you can use for your ratio calculation (your ratio is about 4 queries/s).

Comment: thanks. This is helpful. Also, there is no way for us to determine the number of internal domains requests and external domains requests, correct? TotalQueries is the only entry I see that covers all DNS queries.